# Change Paragraph Heading text in Google Docs using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Docs with the following style:

[image: What I have]

The actual TOC is:

[image: Table Of Contents]

You can see it has a few styles:

- Title (14pt, in blue, underlined)
- Subtitle (12pt, in black, underlined)
- Header 1 (11pt)
- Header 2 (10pt, in bold)
- Normal text (10pt)

I would like to make a script that runs on the active document and store the content of each heading to make the following changes:

- Header 1 (14pt, in blue, underlined)
- Header 2 (11pt)
- Normal text (10pt, the first line contains "Topic nº)" in bold)

The final result after running the script should be:

[image: What I want]

The new TOC should look like:

[image: New Table Of Contents]

So the main change is to put HEADER 2 content into a Normal text line so it dissapears from TOC. Is there any way to code a script that solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See script below:

```
function findHeader() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  // Define the search parameters
  var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  var searchHeadings = [DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2, DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1, DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.TITLE];
  var replacementHeadings = [DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL, DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2, DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1];
  var searchResult = null;
  
  // Style changes you want to apply
  var H2_N = {};
  H2_N[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '11';
  // Since HEADING 2 that are made to be Normal becomes first Normal heading and first Normal heading is to be bold, 
  // You can directly make it bold here to reduce redundancy
  H2_N[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;

  var H1_H2 = {};
  H1_H2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '11';

  var T_H1 = {};
  T_H1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = '14';
  T_H1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#0000FF';
  T_H1[DocumentApp.Attribute.UNDERLINE] = true;

  var styles = [H2_N, H1_H2, T_H1];

  // Loop all searchHeadings
  searchHeadings.forEach((searchHeading, index) => {  
    // Search until the wanted searchHeading is found
    while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
      var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
      if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {
        // Replace with its corresponding replacementHeadings and apply approriate styles
        par.setHeading(replacementHeadings[index]);
        par.setAttributes(styles[index]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Script Behavior Summary:

- Demotes the following headings (`T -> H1`, `H1 -> H2`, `H2 -> N`)
- Applies different styles per demotion:

  - `T -> H1`: 14PT, BLUE, UNDERLINED
  - `H1 -> H2`: 11PT
  - `H2 -> N`: 11PT, BOLD
- `H2 -> N` is directly turned to bold as you want the first N paragraph to be bold. And when H2 is demoted, it turns into N and becomes the first N. So we can directly turn H2 into bold when demoted.

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### References:

- [Paragraph Heading](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading)
- [Attribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer!! Although I didn't say it explicitly in the question, is there any way to also change Title to Header 1 (new Header 1 should be 14pt, in blue, underlined) and Header 1 changes to Header 2 (new Header 2 should be 11pt)? Your code works very well, but it's not complete.

Comment: So you mean, changes left are. `Title -> Header 1` and `Header 1 -> Header 2`?

Comment: Yes. I guess we need to create a style vector for each new style.

Comment: I have also included the first Normal heading to be bold. See change, behavior and output.

Comment: Thanks!! Now the headings are in the correct position. I think you missed `var style1={}, style2={}, style3={};`. However the styles aren't applied. I think it's because my document already has defined a style for each Heading. It seems the code doesn't override them because the Style menu in Google Docs (next to Font menu) didn't change after the code ran. Do you know if I am right and how can we solve this?

Comment: Also, after the script ran, the bold font is not applied in the first paragraph. It's like it doesn't care any of the style put in the code. I tested it adding bold to Normal text in the Style menu in my Document, then run the script, and the bold is applied to the first paragraph (now I have a lot of bold in my document but it was for tests purpose).

Comment: I modified the instantiation but the assignment of styles were left as is that's why styles weren't applied. I have updated the script and it should work now @manooooh